# camel sftp special characters in user name

Tags: apache-camel, sftp

I am using Apache Camel 2.13.2 and trying to connect to an sftp which has special characters in the Username.  The username is something like 'XXX\XX-XXXXXXX'.  The camel URL at the end gets converted into something like below, and the authentication is failing.   Could someone throw some light on how to deal with these special characters in the username?

```
Endpoint[sftp://XXX%5CXX-xxxxxxx@99.999.99.99:22//folder_Test/?binary=true&consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true&delay=15000&idempotent=true&idempotentKey=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D-%24%7Bfile%3Asize%7D-%24%7Bfile%3Amodified%7D&include=.*Test.*&maxMessagesPerPoll=30&password=xxxxxx&pollStrategy=%23FTPPollingConsumerPollStrategy&readLock=changed&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&stepwise=false&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true]
```

The below is the exception that I am seeing in the logs.

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot connect to sftp://XXX\XX-XXXXX@99.999.99.99:22
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.connect(SftpOperations.java:143)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.connectIfNecessary(RemoteFileConsumer.java:154)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.recoverableConnectIfNecessary(RemoteFileConsumer.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.prePollCheck(RemoteFileConsumer.java:55)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:106)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:187)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:114)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:512)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.connect(SftpOperations.java:115)
    ... 15 more
```

The same credentials for the sftp work while using fileZilla or Apache FTP Utilities.

Answer (score 5):

See the documentation how to configure endpoints, especially about passwords: http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html where you need to use the RAW syntax. You can use the RAW syntax to specify the username/password as an uri parameter instead of in the start of the uri.

Comment: I have tried using RAW for the user name but it did not work giving me the same Authentication error. Any other ideas I could try?

Comment: Using RAW with username as a parameter works, that is instead of using username@sftp://host:port if you use sftp://host:port?username=RAW(XXXX) it works.  But still the character "\" is still a problem even while using RAW, it does not authenticate.   Liked Camel so far, but just for this one scenario, I would have to find another way of doing connecting, downloading and uploading files :(

Comment: Came across your post with a problem I was having with special characters in username and RAW worked.  Appreciate the post Claus!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a late response for the original question, but it can still be helpful for others. RAW() works for most cases indeed, however, if your ftp password contains special characters, such as "\" in Ravi's case, you can simply escape them.

For example this password would not work:

```
password=RAW(a@b$c/d\e)
```

So it needs to be changed to:

```
password=RAW(a@b$c/d\\e)
```